# Linphone UWP client - no functional build

Tags: build, uwp, sip, voip, linphone

I have tried to build the (now outdated) UWP client dozens of times. I follow the instructions to the letter: i download the repository using "git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-windows10.git --recursive"  (it is outdated - but can't find the new one anywhere), i then run the prepare.py script (first with -c flag to remove previous instances, then without), i then open the SDK.sln project and build it (it gives errors), i then build the project itself (Linphone.sln) and run it. After it builds, it gives hundreds of errors because the Linphone Core is missing.

I fixed this by downloading the latest already-built SDK (my version gives errors during build) and importing the assembly reference "BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.Native.winmd". After that it builds but gives "Class not registered" exceptions and gets stuck at splash screen. I fixed those exceptions by placing the (x64-current) corresponding DLL file in the same folder, so "BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.Native.winmd" and "BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.Native.dll" (x64) are in the same folder.

Finally, after that it gives "File not found" exceptions and like before gets stuck on the splash screen.

I pretty much gave hope of ever building this for UWP...i made this post in the hopes of either:

a. Getting some help from people who got through this

(AND/OR)

b. Getting the location of the new UWP version (one that was released just days ago) - reasonable chance that would work.

Comment: What nuget package you are using? What't the version of your uwp app? What's the package version you are using? For voip in uwp can you use [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VoIP)?

Comment: Hi @SunteenWu-MSFT. I am stuck at the same point. I installed [LinphoneSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinphoneSDK/) v3.10.2.881 package. I also took a look at your sample project but it seems that it is only applicable for Windows Phone UWP projects but not Windows 10 Desktop UWP projects.